# jQuery Youtube URL Validation with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, youtube

I know there is plenty of question answered over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube+regex, but not able find a question similar to me.

Any body has the JavaScript Regular expression for validating the YouTube VIDEO URL's line below listed. Just want to know where such a URL can be possible

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQVoAWSP7k4
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQVoAWSP7k4&feature=popular
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McNqjYiFmyQ&feature=related&bhablah
http://youtube.com/watch?v=bQVoAWSP7k4
```

-- update 1--
-- update 2--

This one worked almost fine, but failed for the URL http://youtube.com/watch?v=bQVoAWSP7k4

```
var matches = $('#videoUrl').val().match(/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.*watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/);
if (matches) {
    alert('valid');
} else {
    alert('Invalid');
}
```

Comment: That regex you have there is very troublesome. Particularly the `.*` portion which matches anything. This means that it would also match the following url: `http://hackersrus.com/youtube-watch?v=a`

Comment: oops! changed to var matches = $('#videoUrl').val().match(/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.*watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/);
if (matches) {
    alert('valid');
} else {
    alert('Invalid');
}

Comment: Still false, see my answer for a fully correct way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?v=\w+(&\S*)?$

//if v can be anywhere in the query list

^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?:\S+)?$
```

Comment: Great one but failed for http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=US&hl=en-US&v=bQVoAWSP7k4

Comment: youtube.com part in your regexp can match anything like youtubeXcom, you should escape that period

Comment: see my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10315969/624466) for an improved version.

Comment: @Amarghosh ,  can you please do courtecy of telling which urls out of 2 are correct? Is it very difficult to give some explanation ?

Answer (score 199):

## ULTIMATE YOUTUBE REGEX

### Cherry picking

Because the explanation is getting longer and longer, I place the final result at the top. Feel free to copy+paste, and go on your way. For a detailed explanation, read _"the full story"_ below.

```
/**
 * JavaScript function to match (and return) the video Id 
 * of any valid Youtube Url, given as input string.
 * @author: Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 * @url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10315969/624466
 */
function ytVidId(url) {
  var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
  return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}
```

### The full story

[Amarghosh's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2964758/624466) looks good, at first sight. But it:

1. doesn't match video id's that include dashes (-),
2. doesn't validate the id length (`v=aa` and `v=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` return to be valid),
3. and doesn't match secured URLs at all (http**s**://youtube.com/watch?valid_params)

To match https, the dash character, and to validate the id length, this was my initial suggestion of a modified version of Amarghosh's regex:

`^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$`

### UPDATE 1: URLs versus Strings

After I posted the above pattern, I was asked: *"What if the **URL** is like this;

`youtube.com/watch?gl=US&hl=en-US&v=bQVoAWSP7k4`"*?

First of, please note that this not a **URL** at all. [RFC compliant URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-16) must start with the scheme! ;)

Anyway, to match any kind of **string** that indicates to refer to a YouTube video, I updated my answer to exclude the URL scheme being required. So my second suggestion was as follows:

`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$`

### UPDATE 2: The ultimate regex

Then I was asked to add support for a "special case"; the *youtu.be* short urls. Initially I did not add these, since it wasn't specifically part of the question. However I updated my answer now with **all** possible *"special cases"*. This means that not only have I added support for youtu.be links, but also the request paths "/v" and "/embed".

So, may I introduce: My final and ultimate Youtube regex:

`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$`

### What strings are matched?

Now this pattern will work for any strings, formatted as follows:

**Without scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtu.be, Path: /)**

```
youtu.be/<video:id>
```

**Without scheme, with subdomain (Domain: youtu.be, Path: /)**

```
www.youtu.be/<video:id>
```

**With HTTP scheme, without subdomain (Domain: youtu.be, Path: /)**

```
http://youtu.be/<video:id>
```

**With HTTP scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtu.be, Path: /)**

```
http://www.youtu.be/<video:id>
```

**With HTTPS scheme, without subdomain (Domain: youtu.be, Path: /)**

```
https://youtu.be/<video:id>
```

**With HTTPS scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtu.be, Path: /)**

```
https://www.youtu.be/<video:id>
```

**Without scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /embed)**

```
youtube.com/embed/<video:id>   
youtube.com/embed/<video:id>&other_params
```

**Without scheme, with subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /embed)**

```
www.youtube.com/embed/<video:id>   
www.youtube.com/embed/<video:id>&other_params
```

**With HTTP scheme, without subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /embed)**

```
http://youtube.com/embed/<video:id>   
http://youtube.com/embed/<video:id>&other_params
```

**With HTTP scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /embed)**

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/<video:id>   
http://www.youtube.com/embed/<video:id>&other_params
```

**With HTTPS scheme, without subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /embed)**

```
https://youtube.com/embed/<video:id>   
https://youtube.com/embed/<video:id>&other_params
```

**With HTTPS scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /embed)**

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/<video:id>   
https://www.youtube.com/embed/<video:id>&other_params
```

**Without scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /v)**

```
youtube.com/v/<video:id>   
youtube.com/v/<video:id>&other_params
```

**Without scheme, with subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /v)**

```
www.youtube.com/v/<video:id>   
www.youtube.com/v/<video:id>&other_params
```

**With HTTP scheme, without subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /v)**

```
http://youtube.com/v/<video:id>   
http://youtube.com/v/<video:id>&other_params
```

**With HTTP scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /v)**

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/<video:id>   
http://www.youtube.com/v/<video:id>&other_params
```

**With HTTPS scheme, without subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /v)**

```
https://youtube.com/v/<video:id>   
https://youtube.com/v/<video:id>&other_params
```

**With HTTPS scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /v)**

```
https://www.youtube.com/v/<video:id>   
https://www.youtube.com/v/<video:id>&other_params
```

**Without scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /watch)**

```
youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>   
youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>&other_params   
youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id> 
youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>&more_params
```

**Without scheme, with subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /watch)**

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>   
www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>&other_params   
www.youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>  
www.youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>&more_params
```

**With HTTP scheme, without subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /watch)**

```
http://youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>   
http://youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>&other_params   
http://youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>   
http://youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>&more_params
```

**With HTTP scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /watch)**

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>   
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>&other_params   
http://www.youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>   
http://www.youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>&more_params
```

**With HTTPS scheme, without subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /watch)**

```
https://youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>   
https://youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>&other_params   
https://youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>   
https://youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>&more_params
```

**With HTTPS scheme and subdomain (Domain: youtube.com, Path: /watch)**

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>   
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<video:id>&other_params   
https://www.youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?other_params&v=<video:id>&more_params
```

### FUNCTIONAL USAGE

The most easy way to use the pattern, is to wrap it into a function such as this one:

```js
/**
 * JavaScript function to match (and return) the video Id
 * of any valid Youtube Url, given as input string.
 * @author: Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 * @url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10315969/624466
 */
function ytVidId(url) {
  var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
  return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}

// for example snippet only!
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'yt-url' && 'undefined' !== e.target.value) {
        var ytId = ytVidId(e.target.value);
        alert(e.target.value + "\r\nResult: " + (!ytId ? 'false' : ytId));
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<!-- Click the buttons to probe URLs -->
<input type="button" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-e2G_VcTms&feature=g-logo&context=G29aead6FOAAAAAAABAA" class="yt-url">
<input type="button" value="https://www.youtube.com/latest" class="yt-url">
```

If the type of the function's result value must be a boolean value, just replace `RegExp.$1` by `true`. That's it.

**One final note on the video Id length**: One asked if the ids have a fixed length of 11 chars? and if it might change in the future?

The best answer to that question is probably also the only "official" statement that I've found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/oAztQ3f1tcM) and which says: *"I don't see anywhere in the documentation where we officially commit to a standard length of 11 characters for YouTube video ids. It's one of those things where we have a current implementation, and it may stay that way indefinitely. But we're not offering any official commitment to that, so proceed at your own risk."*

Comment: youtube.com part in your regexp can match anything like youtubeXcom, you should escape that period

Comment: What if the URL is like this; http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=US&hl=en-US&v=bQVoAWSP7k4

Comment: @FizzBuzz Well, that is not a valid URL at all (even though (most) web browsers will accept this input)! [RFC compliant URLs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-16) must provide _a means of locating the resource by describing its primary access mechanism_ which refers to the valid URI syntax that always starts with the access scheme. However, you could make the scheme optional in the regex like this: `var pattern = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$/;` Does that answer your question?

Comment: What about http://youtu.be/_d6KuiuteIA which you get if you select the embed option?

Comment: @DanDiplo: I focused on "watch"-URLs, since the question did. But you can easily expand the pattern to group path alternatives, too. Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10524505/624466. The pattern is used with PHP, but you can easily adapt it for use with JS.

Comment: there is another special case to add: http://youtu.be/8mwKq7_JlS8 I'm talking about the links provided by share button provided by youtube webapp which use youtu.be

Comment: @doledoug: The question about _youtu.be_ URL-like strings was already answered (see question from Dan Diplo upthread). However, I updated the answer now. Is that what you're looking for? ;-) Now there shouldn't be any more _"special cases"_ to add. This should be the ultimate regex now.

Comment: I've made it even more ultimate by making it work correctly and also support the `-nocookie` domain: `/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com\/)(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|\-){11})(?:\S+)?$/`

Comment: It worked correctly before. :P But thanks for the update anyway! Will add it to the answer later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great solution.
Also a special thanks for being so specific!

Comment: Awesome job, you won my internets. This should be "sticky" lol

Comment: check this buddy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362164/what-does-regexp-1-do/18362308#18362308

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Reconsidering when to replace it. Thanks.

Comment: It gives following warning "nested repeat operator '+' and '?' was replaced with '*' in regular expression"

Comment: @eyecatchUp badly need a youtube "playlist" ultimate youtube regex :) work your magic :D or maybe I can do this :D

Comment: Not really "ultimate", the provided expression will fail with any Youtube url sent via channel subscription, like this: "**http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=Od7TH6HFkco&u=/watch?v%3DHzmn4-vtl5M%26feature%3Dem-uploademail**", also, I'm not sure if the current expression is validating other fields such as "**&feature=em-uploademail**", any update to this, please?. thanks in advance!

Comment: **RegExp.$1-$9** [is Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Properties)

Comment: The last part: `(?:\S+)?`. Why to use two repeat operators (+, ?)? [gives me a warning in ruby]. Isn't `(?:\S*)` more convenient?

Comment: This seems to validate for video IDs longer than 11 characters too. Any ideas how to fix? Also, any replacement for RegExp.$1? Seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Can anyone get this to work with HTML input pattern? ie **<input
    type="url"
    pattern="(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$"
    required** It always fails on form submit

Comment: @ElektroStudios this really should be a gist now or even repo

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Not sure, what exactly fails. But for me the regex works fine as an input pattern as well. See https://codepen.io/eyecatchup/pen/mdrxzmj

Comment: How do you make it still work if the string contains a youtube link with some text. For example, 'check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZk4vbLG0jU '

Comment: @JoshuaBitton Just remove the leading `^` and trailing `$` from the regex, like so: `/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?/`. See: https://codepen.io/eyecatchup/pen/jOVaovX

Comment: how would you be able to return the link and console.log the message in the string, so it would be a string containing the youtube link and the message

Comment: Can we get this to work with shorts? Like with this link [https://www.youtube.com/shorts/jhX_oSfYGiI](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/jhX_oSfYGiI)

Answer (score 4):

You can not match the id-part with \w+, as it does not include the dash character (-). [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ would be something more correct.

Comment: You can not validate the id length with +, {11} would be something more correct. ;)

Comment: Forgot to mention that (\w|-) is shorter than [a-zA-Z0-9_-]. :p ;)

Comment: is ids fixed to 11 chars? it might be change in the future?

Comment: The best answer to that question is probably also the only "official" statement i've found here http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/a00ced4377f5b5c3/e3602552c32f376f and which says "I don't see anywhere in the documentation where we officially commit to a standard length of 11 characters for YouTube video ids. It's one of those things where we have a current implementation, and it may stay that way indefinitely. But we're not offering any official commitment to that, so proceed at your own risk."

Answer (score 2):

@eyecatchup ubove has an excelent regex, but with the help of regexper.com 
i saw that his regex will pass any youtube url where the ?v parameter had a value of any word or - sign repeated 11 times. But youtube specificly restricts the video id to 11 characters so a fix for his regex would be

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((.|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/
```

compare the vizualization of his regex

```
http://www.regexper.com/#/%5E%28?:https?:%5C/%5C/%29?%28?:www%5C.%29?%28?:youtu%5C.be%5C/%7Cyoutube%5C.com%5C/%28?:embed%5C/%7Cv%5C/%7Cwatch%5C?v=%7Cwatch%5C?.%2b&v=%29%29%28%28%5Cw%7C-%29%7B11%7D%29%28?:%5CS%2b%29?$/
```

and my fix

```
http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E(%3F%3Ahttps%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F)%3F(%3F%3Awww%5C.)%3F(%3F%3Ayoutu%5C.be%5C%2F%7Cyoutube%5C.com%5C%2F(%3F%3Aembed%5C%2F%7Cv%5C%2F%7Cwatch%5C%3Fv%3D%7Cwatch%5C%3F.%2B%26v%3D))((%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%7C-)%7B11%7D)(%3F%3A%5CS%2B)%3F%24%2F
```

as an edit to the 11 character limit changing in future then the current regex would mean that any word or - would have to be repeated exactly 11 times, to that my fix is

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11,})(?:\S+)?$/
```

Comment: Seems to be no longer working. It validates video IDs longer than 11 characters too.

Answer (score 1):

Improvement for @eyecatchUp's great regex:

1. Add support for m.youtube.com domain
2. Add support for youtube-nocookie.com domain by @Nijikokun

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$
```

Regexper:

```
http://regexper.com/#%5E(%3F%3Ahttps%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F)%3F(%3F%3A(%3F%3Awww%7Cm)%5C.)%3F(%3F%3Ayoutu%5C.be%5C%2F%7Cyoutube(%3F%3A-nocookie)%3F%5C.com%5C%2F(%3F%3Aembed%5C%2F%7Cv%5C%2F%7Cwatch%5C%3Fv%3D%7Cwatch%5C%3F.%2B%26v%3D))((%5Cw%7C-)%7B11%7D)(%3F%3A%5CS%2B)%3F%24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 /* test youtube */
 var src = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCPLKrRguDM";
  regExTestYT(src);
   function regExTestYT(str){
   var exp = new RegExp(/(youtu\.be|youtube\.com)/);
   return exp.test(str); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with Youtube shorts added:

`/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|(?:shorts\/)|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/`

Answer (score -3):

```
function get_youtube_video_id_from_url(url){
    var code = url.match(/v=([^&#]{5,})/)
    return (typeof code[1] == 'string') ? code[1] : false;
}
```

Comment: Wrong at all. This matches even `var url = 'v=abcde';`. Furthermore, if no match is found, you produce a `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`.

Answer (score -5):

```
function validYT(url) {
  var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$/;
  return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
}
```

Comment: Congrats. You posted an outdated version of my code above.