# How to Check Youtube URL in ASP.Net?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am working on ASP>Net site and my client wants when any user insert a youtube URL in his/her profile at that time my c# code or any JQuery Code or any youtube API code check this URL that it is exist on youtube.com or not. I have found many things but most of them give us string matcher or URL pattern checker code but my requirement is check this URL i.e. exist on youtube.com and this video is show for public video.

Can anyone help me out.....

Comment: I see that your certifications and experience have made you quite the problem solver! `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Match pattern of URL against known pattern of YouTube video [See Stack Overflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964678/jquery-youtube-url-validation-with-regex)
2. Use AJAX call to your server to screen scrape the entered URL and check for 404 header or typical text resulting in "The video you have requested is not available." using the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for c#.

I can write this for you but it will cost you. :)

Comment: I have used regular expression validator and jQuery validator for check the URL Pattern but my client wants to this URL is exist on youtube or not....

Comment: See step #2 and that should help you out.