# How to apply regex to a webpage for a text-string URL and a previous line of text before that?

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

Hi guys thanks for pay attention to this. Well im trying to replace every full youtube url with a word. An Example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDC0gdrcauI Should be replaced with the word "Video"
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ef0wk8QoA34&feature=g-all-u Should be replaced with the word "Video"
```

Here is my code thus far.  HTML:

```
<p>My brother is great.</p>
<p>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ef0wk8QoA34</p>
```

​
And JS:

```
(function($) {

    $(function(){
    var thePage = $("body");
    thePage.html(thePage.html().replace(/My brother/g, 'My Pig').replace(/youtube.com/g, 'video'));
    });

})(jQuery)
```

​A JSFiddle can be found here:  http://jsfiddle.net/QmRc7/2/

So if you could help me with that ill be great! Thanks!

PS: Sorry guys my post was edited not by me :/

Solved! I just add this and works great +1 for everyone!:

```
.replace(/(www.)?youtu(be\.com|\.be)\/(watch\?v=)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/g, '')
```

Comment: So? Any questions?

Comment: Yeah, works for me.  What's the problem?

Comment: Look at jQuery `.each();` method to process your function after the correct **regex** has been obtained. Reference [**HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours ... I finally got solved this with your help obviously.

```
.replace(/(www.)?youtu(be\.com|\.be)\/(watch\?v=)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/g, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly (from it's title), you want to filter anchor tags using regex on their content(text):

You can do it [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CCLvz/) way:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$/g);
}).each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/youtube.com/g, 'video'));
});
```

​
the code basically, selects anchor tags with text matching youtube url pattern which I copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10315969/303270) answer and for each matching anchor tag, replaces `youtube.com` with `video`.

---

## Answer to updated question:

you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tGSMf/):

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=((\w|-){11}))(?:\S+)?$/g);
}).each(function() {
    $(this).text('Video');
});
```

Note that it doesn't match non anchor tags, you can use `$('*')` instead of `$('a')` to select all nodes.

---

And the second word change can be done easily in this way:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/My brother/g, 'My Pig'));
});
```

Needless to say, you should change the selectors to match your desired nodes.

Comment: I created the question since it was causing issues. The OP did clarify, as well as the example that was provided, the Youtube URL is a text string in `<p>` tags. That said, using `$('p')` as the selector should be the same. Please feel free to edit the question if you have a cleaner version to use, as this is a unique requirement for the OP. Thanks.

Comment: **+1** to include `.filter` along with `.each`. The only thing missing is to include the 2nd word change for the 2nd $('p') that's before the first one.

Comment: @arttronics I'd rather not to change the OP question as it's still not clear and any edits may change it completely.

Comment: To clarify: No `anchors` are used. The Youtube link is a text string as seen in the jsFiddle that the OP provided. That said, it's in the `<p>` tags that you can plainly see.

Comment: @fardjad Thanks guys! I edit my post  so i wanna ask if it's possible to "hide" every url related to youtube (no HTML link refered just text)?.

Answer (score 1):

This regex might need a bit more tweaking to get all the possible youtube URL patterns, but this would be a good start:

```
http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/[\w?=&-]+
```

Comment: A good start yes, but there are a few well accepted **SO Answers** for **Youtube Regex** that look rather horrifying as a regex should.

Comment: @mark-lybrand how i could implement your code in my function?. Sorry im pretty new in this.

Comment: It looks like the answer below mine (from fardjad) should get you on the right track :)