# How to identify whether this URL is from Youtube or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I am using following function to parse YouTube URL to retrieve a YouTube ID from a YouTube URL:

```
function yt_parser()
{
    var yt_url_sub = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nZlXB5okeo; 
    var youtube_id = yt_url_sub.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");
    alert(youtube_id);  
}
```

> output : 6nZlXB5okeo

but how should I validate whether this URL is from YouTube or not?

Comment: Well, the host being `youtube.com` is a strong indication... however, Youtube also uses `youtu.be`. You'll never be able to tell with 100% certainty I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match

Comment: I think this post will do exactly what you're wanting with any valid youtube URL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10315969/485418

Answer (score 1):

You can change your regex for this

```
var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBnCURIfbPg'

var m = url.match(/:\/\/www.youtube.com\/.*?\bv=([^&]+)/);

if (m) {
  alert(m[1]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmDZp/