# What does RegExp.$1 do

Tags: javascript, regex

I have come across a piece of code in JScript:

```
RegExp.$1
```

Does anybody know what it does?

If I output it on its own, I get nothing not even an error.

I can't find any reference to it at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

There was a regex search just prior to this piece of code, which I suspect has something to do with it:

```
.search(/^__product\[(.+)\]$/)
```

Comment: It gets the value of the 1st capture group of the last regex ran.

Comment: What would be the first capture group in my last regex ran?

Comment: Capture groups are parenthesis (`()`).  So, it would be the `(.+)`.  In your case, the text inside the `[]`.

Comment: I would advise against using this method, because if you have other code which manages to invoke after your last _RegExp_ but before you lookup `RegExp.$1` (e.g. setTimeout or an event firing), you can end up with unexpected values.

Comment: I'd advise against it too, because I cannot find documentation of it.  I just kinda guessed what I did after some testing in Chrome's console.

Comment: I found some docs on this.  They say it's deprecated.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Properties

Comment: P.S. Off topic, but I'd suggest Mozilla's docs over w3schools'.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The literal expression `RegExp.$1` will get you the value of the first capture group of the last regex ran.  Whatever that regex was.

For example:

```
var match = /_(.*)_/.exec('_test_');

var newMatch = '123-abc'.match(/(\d*)-(\w*)/);
var num = RegExp.$1; // '123';
```

`RegExp.$1` is globally available, so it can be accessed from anywhere in your page, regardless of where the regex itself was ran.

I've never seen this syntax used before seeing this question, and I wouldn't suggest using it, as I cannot find documentation on it.  Also, *any* regex ran on your page, regardless of where, will modify this property.  If you want to get the capture groups, I'd use the arrays returned from `String.match` or `RegExp.exec` instead.

EDIT: I found some documentation about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/24th3sah(v=vs.94).aspx

EDIT 2: I found some more info about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Properties

`RegExp.$1` is deprecated.  That means future browsers might remove this "feature", so I suggest not using it.

Comment: Gotta love how Mozilla says it's deprecated and Microsoft doesn't :-P

Answer (score 3):

`$1` will return the first group that matches a regular expression.

In your example, the value stored in `$1` is whatever was matching `.+`

The group is denoted by parenthesis and you can have multiples.  Each saved group will just increment the digit with the `$`, i.e. `$1, $2, $3...`

Example:

If your input was `__product[Version 12 Coupe]` then `$1` would contain `Version 12 Coupe`

Answer (score 3):

These work in conjunction with capturing parentheses. For example, `/(foo)/` matches and remembers 'foo' in "foo bar." The matched substring can be recalled from the resulting array's elements [1], ..., [n] or from the predefined RegExp object's properties $1, ..., $9.

In your example, the `$1` refers to the match made by `(.+)`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is whatever is matched in the first capture. If you have more captures you can use `$2`, `$3` etc.

Ex:

```
"abc".replace(/(.)/, "$1$1"); // aabc
"abc".replace(/(.{2})/, "$1$1"); // ababc
"abc".replace(/(.)(.)/, "$2$1"); // bac
```

Answer (score 1):

To add some details:

(As already said,) the `RegExp.$n`-property (where `n` is a single digit 1-9) returns the last `n`<sup>th</sup> parenthesized (captured) substring in a match.

These properties were first implemented in JavaScript 1.2 and deprecated in JavaScript 1.5 - when `RegExp` underwent a major change and many of the results from `RegExp.prototype.exec(string)` were moved from the `RegExp` object to the `RegExp` instance and all the `.$` properties (and their full name versions (except for `.multiline`)) "went away".

---

The **non-standard**<sup>1</sup> `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, `$5`, `$6`, `$7`, `$8`, `$9` properties are **static** and **read-only** properties of regular expressions (that contain parenthesized substring matches) and are **modified whenever successful matches are made**.

They are **not a property of an individual regular expression object**. Instead, you always use them as `RegExp.$1`, ..., `RegExp.$9`.

The number of possible parenthesized substrings is unlimited (of course), but the `RegExp` object can only hold the last nine.

*<sup>1</sup> Non-standard = Not part of any current specification!*

---

You can find the definition and references in the following sections of the [*ECMA-262 3*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) Specs:

- 15.5.4.10 - `String.prototype.match(regexp)`
- 15.5.4.11 - `String.prototype.replace(regexp)`
- 15.10.2.1 -  The RegExp Object Notation's *NCapturingParens*
- 15.10.6.2 - `RegExp.prototype.exec(string)`

Answer (score 0):

Like stated earlier, these constructs are called capturing parentheses groups and they're primarily used to reference the matches saved/remembered following the successful execution of an RegExp related operation.

Also, like stated earlier, I don't advise using any of them in your code unless a well controlled environment/context is secured, like the one provided by the native `replace()` method found on the `String.prototype` object.