# What is wrong with my validation code? (Regex is fine)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using the regex here [jQuery Youtube URL Validation with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964678/jquery-youtube-url-validation-with-regex)

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$
```

It works fine here https://regex101.com/#javascript

But my code is not working- I am using jquery.validate.min.js and additional-methods.js

My code below works fine with other Regexes but with this one is not working, it always says invalid:

```
var yt = new RegExp("^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$");

$("#submit-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        yturl: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            pattern: yt
        }

    },
    messages: {
        yturl: {
            pattern: "Wrong url"
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use strings and the `RegExp()` constructor unless you have to. Use a native regular expression literal:

```
var yt = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
```

The string lexical grammar also recognizes backslash characters as metacharacters, so you have to quote them by doubling them. If you use the notation for a regular expression literal, you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks, that worked !