# CSS or jQuery not working inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website where in header I try to inspire people with a text that is constantly changing with javascript. One of the lines that appear among this text includes a link to the video, which was supposed to be a modal video, but it somehow fails to load properly while other videos outside this of this javascript work just fine. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhewkwi83dddga8/output.mkv?dl=0) is the video of the problem.

I am not sure, what isn't working here. Is it CSS or jQuery?

```html
<!doctype HTML> 
<html lang="en-US"> 
<head>
    <!-- load latest jQuery 3.1.1 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <style>
            .modal.fade.in {
            top: 20%;
        }
        .fade.in {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .modal.fade {
            -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
            -o-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
            transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
            top: -25%;
        }
        .fade {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
            transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
        }
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
        .modal {
            position: fixed;
            top: 10%;
            left: 50%;
            z-index: 1050;
            width: 560px;
            margin-left: -280px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
            -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            outline: none;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        .modal-header {
            padding: 9px 15px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        }
        .modal-header .close {
            margin-top: 2px;
        }
        .close {
            float: right;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 20px;
            color: #000000;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
            opacity: 0.2;
            filter: alpha(opacity=20);
            font-size: 45px;
            height: 50px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .modal-body {
            position: relative;
            max-height: 80%;
            overflow-y: visible;
            padding: 5px;
            margin-bottom: -4px;
        }

        .modal-body.modal-body-video iframe {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .modal-backdrop,
        .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
            opacity: 0.8;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        }
        .modal-backdrop {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1040;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        .modal-header .link {
            white-space: normal;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            .modal.fade.in {
                top: 20px;
            }
            .modal {
                position: fixed;
                top: 20px;
                left: 20px;
                right: 20px;
                width: auto;
                margin: 0;
            }
        }
        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            .modal {
                top: 10px;
                left: 10px;
                right: 10px;
            }
        }   
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding-left: 10%;
            padding-right: 10%;
            padding-top: 2%;
            padding-bottom: 1%;
        }
        #moto{
            margin-top: -20px;
            font-size: 1.7vw;
            text-align: center;
            height: 5vw;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .boxspace {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .box {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            width: 16.6666%;
            padding-bottom: 16.6666%;
        }
        .boxInner {
            position: absolute;
            left: 2%;
            right: 2%;
            top: 2%;
            bottom: 2%;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: thin solid #969696;
            border-radius: 4%;
        }
        .boxInner .titleBox {
            position: absolute;
            /*no top border*/
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            /*we push the square down*/
            margin-bottom: -20%;
            background: #000000;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            color: #FFFFFF;
            padding-top: 2%;
            padding-bottom: 2%;
            padding-left: 2%;
            padding-right: 2%;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.2vw;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        }
        .boxInner .titleBox header{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 1.4vw;
        }
        .boxInner .titleBox p{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 1.0vw;
        }
        body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }


    </style>
    
    <!--VIDEO-scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /// <reference path="../jquery.min.js" />

        //force strict mode
        "use strict";

        /* Modal Video pluggin.
        * currently handles videos in mp4 using html5 native controls && youtube videos
        * currently handles modal click events 
        */

        //scope safe constructor
        function ModalVideoOptions(callbackOnModalOpenClick) {
            if (this instanceof ModalVideoOptions) {

                this.callbackOnModalOpenClick = callbackOnModalOpenClick;
                this._videoType = undefined;

                //we freeze the object if possible
                if (Object.freeze)
                    Object.freeze(this.VideoEnum);   
            }

            else {
                return new ModalVideoOptions(callbackOnModalOpenClick);
            }
        }

        ModalVideoOptions.prototype = {
            constructor: ModalVideoOptions,

            //getters and setters for videoType

            getVideoType : function () {
                return this._videoType;
            },

            setVideoType : function (value) {
                if (typeof value != "number") {
                    throw new Error('Invalid argument: value. This argument must be a number.');
                }

                var videoTypeItem;
                //loop in the enum properties
                for(videoTypeItem in this.VideoEnum) {
                    var enumValue = this.VideoEnum[videoTypeItem];

                    if (value == enumValue) {
                        this._videoType = enumValue;
                    }
                }

                if (this._videoType == undefined)
                    throw new Error('Invalid argument: value. This argument must be in the range of VideoEnum.');
            },

            //enum 

            VideoEnum : {
                MP4: 0,
                YOUTUBE: 1
            }
        };

        /**
        * JavaScript function to match (and return) the video Id 
        * of any valid Youtube Url, given as input string.
        * @author: Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
        * @url: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10315969/624466
        */
        function ytVidId(url) {
            var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
            return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
        }

        (function ($) {
            
            function showModal(options) {
                
                //mask doesn't exist
                if ($('#mask').length == 0) {
                    //we create it
                    $('body').prepend("<div id='mask' class='modal-backdrop fade in'></div>");
                }

                var dialogContainer = $('#dialog-container-video');

                //popup not created yet
                if (dialogContainer.length == 0) {

                    //we create it
                    var dialogContainer = $("<div id='dialog-container-video' class='modal fade in'></div>");
                    $('body').prepend(dialogContainer);

                }

                var dialogContent;

                if (options.getVideoType() == options.VideoEnum.MP4)
                    dialogContent = "<div id='dialog-content' class='modal-body'><video width='100%' src='" + options.link + "' controls></video></div>";

                else if (options.getVideoType() == options.VideoEnum.YOUTUBE)
                    dialogContent = "<div id='dialog-content' class='modal-body modal-body-video'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + options.youtubeId + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>";

                if(dialogContent)
                    dialogContainer.append(dialogContent);
                
                //transition effect
                $('#mask').show();
                $("#dialog-container-video").show();

                //modal only must be visible, so we hide the scrollbars
                $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

                //add here transition effect to hide the modal window
                var closePopup = function () {
                    $('#mask').hide();
                    $('#dialog-container-video').hide();

                    //we unbind at the closing of the modal window
                    $("#mask").unbind("click", closePopup);
                    $('#dialog-container-video a.close').unbind("click", closePopup);
                    $(document).unbind("keyup", escKeyClosePopup);

                    $('#dialog-content').remove();

                    //we display the scrollbars again if needed
                    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                };

                $('#mask').on("click", closePopup);
                $('#dialog-container-video a.close').on("click", closePopup);

                var escKeyClosePopup = function (e) {
                    //escape key
                    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                        closePopup();
                    }
                };

                $(document).keyup(escKeyClosePopup);
            }

            $.fn.modalvideo = function (options) {

                if ((options instanceof ModalVideoOptions) == false)
                    throw new Error('Invalid argument: options. This argument must be an instance of ModalVideoOptions.');

                //force strong-typed object
                if (!options || $.isEmptyObject(options)) {
                    options = new ModalVideoOptions();
                }

                //every link the selector found
                $(this).each(function (i) {

                    //get the url of the link
                    var link = $(this).prop("href");
                    
                    //no href property ? we leave
                    if (typeof link == "undefined") {
                        return true;
                    }

                    var youtubeId = ytVidId(link);

                    //youtube id detected
                    if (youtubeId != false) {
                        //console.log('youtube ID : ' + youtubeId);
                        options.setVideoType(options.VideoEnum.YOUTUBE);
                        options.youtubeId = youtubeId;
                    }

                        //test if the link ends with '.mp4' 
                    else if (link.indexOf('.mp4', link.length - '.mp4'.length) != -1) {
                        options.setVideoType(options.VideoEnum.MP4);
                    }

                    //no mp4 or youtube video, continue to the next link
                    else
                        return true;

                    options.link = typeof options.link == "undefined" ? link : options.link;

                    //binding to the click event. This will cancel the trigger('click') event.
                    $(this).click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        showModal(options);

                        //open modal event

                        if (typeof options.callbackOnModalOpenClick == "function") {
                            options.callbackOnModalOpenClick();
                        }
                    });

                });
            }
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"">
        "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function () {
  
   //each video has need its own instance of modalVideoOptions  
   $('a[href]').each(function(){
    $(this).modalvideo(new ModalVideoOptions());
   });
  });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
</head> 

<body class="no-touch"> 

    <div id="moto"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var text = ["Line 1",'Line 2 and nonworking <a href="./video/test.mp4">video</a>.'];
        var counter = 0;
        var elem = document.getElementById("moto");
        ChangeFunction();
        setInterval(ChangeFunction, 3000);
        function ChangeFunction() {
            var moto = text[counter++];
            $(elem).fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(elem).html(moto);
            $(elem).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
        }
    </script>

    <div class="boxspace">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="boxInner">
                <div class="titleBox">
                    <header>
                    Header title
                    </header>
                    <a href="./video/test.mp4">video</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Mosh Feu Ok the snippet is working now. Try it in full screen - problem is now only in the local mp4 video which isn't found but you can see that video inside of a javascript isn't opened as a modal window. 

I don't know why I got a close vote. I posted video of a problem, code, now snippet...

Comment: I answered you, but now, you can remove all the code outside the snippet because it's not relevant now. The snippet do the job ;)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you replace the **html** in each rotation. So when you replace the html you actually create a **new** DOM elements, including the `a` tag. So the code `$(this).modalvideo(new ModalVideoOptions());` not apply to it.

You have 2 options:

1. Run this line in each rotation (like I did my snippet).
2. Do the rotation using show/hide. I mean, in the first place, add all the "slides" in the html and just show/hide (or fade, never mind) them.

Let me know if something is not clear.

```html
<!doctype HTML> 
<html lang="en-US"> 
  <head>
    <!-- load latest jQuery 3.1.1 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .modal.fade.in {
        top: 20%;
      }
      .fade.in {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      .modal.fade {
        -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
        transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
        top: -25%;
      }
      .fade {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
        transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
      }
      .hide {
        display: none;
      }
      .modal {
        position: fixed;
        top: 10%;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 1050;
        width: 560px;
        margin-left: -280px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
        -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        outline: none;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      .modal-header {
        padding: 9px 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
      }
      .modal-header .close {
        margin-top: 2px;
      }
      .close {
        float: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #000000;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
        opacity: 0.2;
        filter: alpha(opacity=20);
        font-size: 45px;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .modal-body {
        position: relative;
        max-height: 80%;
        overflow-y: visible;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-bottom: -4px;
      }

      .modal-body.modal-body-video iframe {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .modal-backdrop,
      .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
      }
      .modal-backdrop {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1040;
        background-color: #000000;
      }
      .modal-header .link {
        white-space: normal;
        margin-left: 5px;
      }
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .modal.fade.in {
          top: 20px;
        }
        .modal {
          position: fixed;
          top: 20px;
          left: 20px;
          right: 20px;
          width: auto;
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
      @media (max-width: 480px) {
        .modal {
          top: 10px;
          left: 10px;
          right: 10px;
        }
      }   
      body{
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right: 10%;
        padding-top: 2%;
        padding-bottom: 1%;
      }
      #moto{
        margin-top: -20px;
        font-size: 1.7vw;
        text-align: center;
        height: 5vw;
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
      .boxspace {
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .box {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 16.6666%;
        padding-bottom: 16.6666%;
      }
      .boxInner {
        position: absolute;
        left: 2%;
        right: 2%;
        top: 2%;
        bottom: 2%;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: thin solid #969696;
        border-radius: 4%;
      }
      .boxInner .titleBox {
        position: absolute;
        /*no top border*/
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        /*we push the square down*/
        margin-bottom: -20%;
        background: #000000;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding-top: 2%;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
        padding-left: 2%;
        padding-right: 2%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.2vw;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      }
      .boxInner .titleBox header{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 1.4vw;
      }
      .boxInner .titleBox p{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 1.0vw;
      }
      body.no-touch .boxInner:hover .titleBox, body.touch .boxInner.touchFocus .titleBox {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
      }


    </style>

    <!--VIDEO-scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      /// <reference path="../jquery.min.js" />

      //force strict mode
      "use strict";

      /* Modal Video pluggin.
        * currently handles videos in mp4 using html5 native controls && youtube videos
        * currently handles modal click events 
        */

      //scope safe constructor
      function ModalVideoOptions(callbackOnModalOpenClick) {
        if (this instanceof ModalVideoOptions) {

          this.callbackOnModalOpenClick = callbackOnModalOpenClick;
          this._videoType = undefined;

          //we freeze the object if possible
          if (Object.freeze)
            Object.freeze(this.VideoEnum);   
        }

        else {
          return new ModalVideoOptions(callbackOnModalOpenClick);
        }
      }

      ModalVideoOptions.prototype = {
        constructor: ModalVideoOptions,

        //getters and setters for videoType

        getVideoType : function () {
          return this._videoType;
        },

        setVideoType : function (value) {
          if (typeof value != "number") {
            throw new Error('Invalid argument: value. This argument must be a number.');
          }

          var videoTypeItem;
          //loop in the enum properties
          for(videoTypeItem in this.VideoEnum) {
            var enumValue = this.VideoEnum[videoTypeItem];

            if (value == enumValue) {
              this._videoType = enumValue;
            }
          }

          if (this._videoType == undefined)
            throw new Error('Invalid argument: value. This argument must be in the range of VideoEnum.');
        },

        //enum 

        VideoEnum : {
          MP4: 0,
          YOUTUBE: 1
        }
      };

      /**
        * JavaScript function to match (and return) the video Id 
        * of any valid Youtube Url, given as input string.
        * @author: Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
        * @url: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10315969/624466
        */
      function ytVidId(url) {
        var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
        return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
      }

      (function ($) {

        function showModal(options) {

          //mask doesn't exist
          if ($('#mask').length == 0) {
            //we create it
            $('body').prepend("<div id='mask' class='modal-backdrop fade in'></div>");
          }

          var dialogContainer = $('#dialog-container-video');

          //popup not created yet
          if (dialogContainer.length == 0) {

            //we create it
            var dialogContainer = $("<div id='dialog-container-video' class='modal fade in'></div>");
            $('body').prepend(dialogContainer);

          }

          var dialogContent;

          if (options.getVideoType() == options.VideoEnum.MP4)
            dialogContent = "<div id='dialog-content' class='modal-body'><video width='100%' src='" + options.link + "' controls></video></div>";

          else if (options.getVideoType() == options.VideoEnum.YOUTUBE)
            dialogContent = "<div id='dialog-content' class='modal-body modal-body-video'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + options.youtubeId + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>";

          if(dialogContent)
            dialogContainer.append(dialogContent);

          //transition effect
          $('#mask').show();
          $("#dialog-container-video").show();

          //modal only must be visible, so we hide the scrollbars
          $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

          //add here transition effect to hide the modal window
          var closePopup = function () {
            $('#mask').hide();
            $('#dialog-container-video').hide();

            //we unbind at the closing of the modal window
            $("#mask").unbind("click", closePopup);
            $('#dialog-container-video a.close').unbind("click", closePopup);
            $(document).unbind("keyup", escKeyClosePopup);

            $('#dialog-content').remove();

            //we display the scrollbars again if needed
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
          };

          $('#mask').on("click", closePopup);
          $('#dialog-container-video a.close').on("click", closePopup);

          var escKeyClosePopup = function (e) {
            //escape key
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
              closePopup();
            }
          };

          $(document).keyup(escKeyClosePopup);
        }

        $.fn.modalvideo = function (options) {

          if ((options instanceof ModalVideoOptions) == false)
            throw new Error('Invalid argument: options. This argument must be an instance of ModalVideoOptions.');

          //force strong-typed object
          if (!options || $.isEmptyObject(options)) {
            options = new ModalVideoOptions();
          }

          //every link the selector found
          $(this).each(function (i) {

            //get the url of the link
            var link = $(this).prop("href");

            //no href property ? we leave
            if (typeof link == "undefined") {
              return true;
            }

            var youtubeId = ytVidId(link);

            //youtube id detected
            if (youtubeId != false) {
              //console.log('youtube ID : ' + youtubeId);
              options.setVideoType(options.VideoEnum.YOUTUBE);
              options.youtubeId = youtubeId;
            }

            //test if the link ends with '.mp4' 
            else if (link.indexOf('.mp4', link.length - '.mp4'.length) != -1) {
              options.setVideoType(options.VideoEnum.MP4);
            }

            //no mp4 or youtube video, continue to the next link
            else
              return true;

            options.link = typeof options.link == "undefined" ? link : options.link;

            //binding to the click event. This will cancel the trigger('click') event.
            $(this).click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              showModal(options);

              //open modal event

              if (typeof options.callbackOnModalOpenClick == "function") {
                options.callbackOnModalOpenClick();
              }
            });

          });
        }
      })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      "use strict";

      $(document).ready(function () {

        //each video has need its own instance of modalVideoOptions  
        $('a[href]').each(function(){
          $(this).modalvideo(new ModalVideoOptions());
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head> 

  <body class="no-touch"> 

    <div id="moto"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var text = ["Line 1",'Line 2 and nonworking <a href="./video/test.mp4">video</a>.'];
      var counter = 0;
      var elem = document.getElementById("moto");
      ChangeFunction();
      setInterval(ChangeFunction, 3000);
      function ChangeFunction() {
        var moto = text[counter++];
        $(elem).fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(elem).html(moto);
          $(elem).fadeIn('slow');
          $(elem).find('a').modalvideo(new ModalVideoOptions());
        });
        if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
      }
    </script>

    <div class="boxspace">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInner">
          <div class="titleBox">
            <header>
              Header title
            </header>
            <a href="./video/test.mp4">video</a>
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </body> 
</html>
```